# Uncaught TypeError: selectedText.split is not a function , what's the wrong with my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to split the text by `,`. However it's throwing an error:

> selectedText.split is not a function

What am I missing?

```js
var selectedText = $('#ToEmail').find(":selected").text().split("@@gmail.com");
console.log('Right side selectedText :' + selectedText + ",");
if (selectedText !== null && selectedText !== "") {
  //remove that item
  var getSelectedITem = document.getElementById("ToEmail");
  getSelectedITem.remove(getSelectedITem.selectedIndex);
  //$("#ToEmail option[value = selectedText]").remove();
  //add that item back to Email dropdown list

  //append the email text
  var resultEmails = selectedText.split(",");
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `selectedText`? Does the `$('#ToEmail').find(":selected")` element exist? There's lots of debugging steps you need to take here.

Comment: because an array does not have split.  `var selectedText = ....text().split("@@gmail.com");`  <-- I am an array

Comment: In the very first line what do you expect `split() ` to return and why?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for quick feedback, I generally selecting the selected item from the multi-select dropdown list, selectedText contains the option that is selected from the drop-down, FYI I just fixed that error using 'String(selectedText).split(',');'

Comment: @epascarello, yes your correct and i fixed that using String(selectedText).split(',');

Comment: Why would you not just store the text and do the split on a different variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, selectedText is an array

```
[..].split(",")
```

which is not a function